# UI : How to edit, save and load a list?

Tags: lists, interface, users, save, inline-edit

I work on a list builder component that the user must be able to build easliy, save and re-open if needed. I precise that only one list can be active.

I didn't find any similar component on the web, here is [my own concept mockup](http://www.biemans.fr/concept2_6.png).

Do you have any idea or any example in mind for a similar component ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it would make more sense to force the user to create the list first, rather than create the elements under it. You can name the CTA "Create a list" if none exists.
Then, once at least one list exists, you can keep your "Create a new list" inside the drop down at the end like you did on your mockup.

Then the "Add an element" could be called "Add a metal" so the user knows what he is adding.

Then the fact that a list has been modified should be transparent to the user, he shouldn't have to save the list or anything : as soon as he has added a new "element" to the list it should be saved.

For removing "elements" of the list, I think it's easy enough, but I would maybe place it a bit further on the right hand side so that the user doesn't click on it by mistake while manipulating the drop down menu.

Comment: Yes, maybe i should force the user to create a new list but don't you think it may be constraining ?  Also the "modified state" is there for allowing the user to create a new copy of the list. It is an alternative for the "save" and "save as" functions